# Vertical align combobox in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

How do I vertical align the dropdown to top in the example below? (Trying to get it to work in [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home))

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {


        // The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        //...
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
     fieldLabel: 'Loooooong Looooong looooooong looooooong looooooong',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a `baseBodyCls` to the `combobox` & in **CSS** give `vertical-align:top;` to that **class**.

```js
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {


        // The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        //...
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
     fieldLabel: 'Loooooong Looooong looooooong looooooong looooooong',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    baseBodyCls:'vertical-align-body',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
    }
});
```

```css
.vertical-align-body{
vertical-align:top;  
}
```

```html
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-4.1.1-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-4.1.1-gpl/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```